# MySQL query subtotal per period where hour is from 2PM on day to 2PM the next day

Tags: mysql, sql, date, hour, subtotal

I have a table of financial transaction datetime and amounts.  I'm already grouping by an ID and summing the amounts, but I would like to see if there is a pure MySQL way of subtotaling these amounts for periods from 2PM to 2PM each day.

Perhaps with a ROLLUP statement?

Here's a simplified version of my query that selects a date range from 2/01 to 2/05

```
SELECT 
    p.paidtime, 
    SUM(p.amount) as PaymentAmount 
FROM payments p 
WHERE (p.paidtime >= '2019-02-01' AND p.paidtime <= '2019-02-05' OR
    p.paidtime LIKE '2019-02-05%') 
GROUP BY p.requestID 
ORDER BY p.paidtime ASC
```

This results in a table like this:

```
paidtime            PaymentAmount
2019-02-01 07:13:53 6809.00
2019-02-01 10:40:17 1605.81
2019-02-01 14:34:21 368.33
2019-02-01 15:18:13 3516.51
2019-02-01 15:25:14 292.74
2019-02-01 15:30:15 732.36
2019-02-01 15:49:39 2440.84
2019-02-02 09:52:39 2663.43
2019-02-04 09:00:09 265.00
2019-02-04 11:32:23 2307.48
2019-02-04 13:20:51 3878.66
2019-02-05 07:20:46 320.00
2019-02-05 07:38:02 154.08
2019-02-05 11:54:55 320.00
2019-02-05 12:02:53 1068.00
2019-02-05 12:04:56 17028.58
2019-02-05 13:28:21 4880.00
2019-02-05 14:25:02 70.00
```

But what I would like to see is like this with subtotals of payment amounts at the break point of 2PM.

```
paidtime            PaymentAmount
2019-02-01 07:13:53 6809.00
2019-02-01 10:40:17 1605.81
                    SUBTOTAL: 8414.81
2019-02-01 14:34:21 368.33
2019-02-01 15:18:13 3516.51
2019-02-01 15:25:14 292.74
2019-02-01 15:30:15 732.36
2019-02-01 15:49:39 2440.84
                    SUBTOTAL: $$$$
2019-02-02 09:52:39 2663.43
2019-02-04 09:00:09 265.00
2019-02-04 11:32:23 2307.48
                    SUBTOTAL: $$$$
2019-02-04 13:20:51 3878.66
2019-02-05 07:20:46 320.00
2019-02-05 07:38:02 154.08
2019-02-05 11:54:55 320.00
2019-02-05 12:02:53 1068.00
2019-02-05 12:04:56 17028.58
2019-02-05 13:28:21 4880.00
                    SUBTOTAL: $$$$
2019-02-05 14:25:02 70.00
                    SUBTOTAL: 70.00
```

I know this can be done easily with PHP and looping through the results, but I'm wondering if there is a way to create the subtotals purely in MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

Never use `like` with date/time values.  MySQL has lots of helpful datetime functions.  Use them.

You can do what you want by subtracting 14 hours (or adding 10 hours):

```
SELECT DATE(p.paidtime - INTERVAL 14 HOUR),
       SUM(p.amount) AS PaymentAmount
FROM payments p
WHERE p.paidtime >= '2019-02-01 14:00:00' 
GROUP BY DATE(p.paidtime - INTERVAL 14 HOUR)
ORDER BY DATE(p.paidtime - INTERVAL 14 HOUR)
```